# Python Bs4 table print(rows) not showing rows

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to python, sorry.

I'm trying to get the information from the table. I just want the code to basically print out the words 'Annual report' but I'm having trouble just getting it to print out the list from the table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://webb-site.com/dbpub/docs.asp?p=134902'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

league_table = soup.find('table', class_= 'numtable')
#print(league_table)

for team in league_table.find_all('tbody'): 
    rows = team.find_all('tr')
    print(rows)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like your `league_table` object has a tbody, go straight to the rows:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://webb-site.com/dbpub/docs.asp?p=134902'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

league_table = soup.find('table', class_= 'numtable')
# print(league_table)

for team in league_table.find_all('tr'): 
    print(team)
```

Comment: That's worked, thank you. Any idea why it doesn't like the use of  'league_table tbody'?

Comment: there is no `tbody` at all

Comment: if it worked, please consider upvoting and accepting this answer:D